# CATIA macro (Input box not working)

Tags: macros, vbscript, vb6

Help My Balloon finding macro is not working with input box, it works only when i manually add the balloon number.. please tell me what i m missing ...Ferdo m expecting you

Language="VBSCRIPT"

Sub CATMain()

Set drawingDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Set selection1 = drawingDocument1.Selection

result = InputBox("Ballon Number ?", "Title") 'The variable is assigned the value entered in the InputBox

selection1.Search "CATDrwSearch.DrwBalloon.BalloonPartName_CAP= result ,all"

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing but the last line looks wrong. I don't know what the docs are for your function but you are passing the string *result* rather than the value of the variable **result** because it is in quotes. Assuming your line is otherwise right ...

```
selection1.Search "CATDrwSearch.DrwBalloon.BalloonPartName_CAP= " & result & ",all"
```